# I have a value 'marks' in a pivot table, how to find student rank based on 'marks' value using query builder?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-query-builder

I have two models Exam and Student, after every student attempts an Exam that marks obtained by her/him is stored in the pivot table exam_user. I need to rank the student based on the marks obtained.

Right now I am using a very inefficient solution for this, which involves a for-loop. Below is the implementation

```
            $rank=0;
            $attempts = DB::table('exam_user')
                    ->where('exam_id',$exam->id)
                    ->orderBy('marks','desc')
                    ->get();
            foreach ($attempts as $attempt) {
                $rank++;
                if($attempt->user_id==Auth::id())
                    break;
            }
```

Is there any way I can determine the rank without using a for loop, simply using the query builder in laravel. I think I am missing some SQL fundamentals here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rank is just the number of people who has a greater value than yours + 1.

Therefore you can just do this:

```
$userMarks = DB::table('exam_user')
    ->select('marks')
    ->where('exam_id', $exam->id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->marks;

$rank = DB::table('exam_user')
    ->where('exam_id', $exam->id)
    ->where('marks', '>', $userMarks)
    ->count() + 1;
```

You can also put this into one query:

```
$userId = Auth::id();
$rank = DB::table('exam_user')
            ->where('exam_id', $exam->id)
            ->whereRaw(
                "marks > (select eu2.marks from exam_user eu2 where eu2.exam_id = {$exam->id} and eu2.user_id = {$userId}) limit 1"
            )
            ->count() + 1;
```

You may also consider making you pivot table `exam_user` as an actual model, and call it something like `Marks`, as it contains important data that you would want to query.

You can then add the following to the `Exam` model:

```
Class Exam {
    // ...
    public function marks() {
        $this->hasMany(Marks::class);
    }    
    // ...
}
```

This means you could do something like:

```
$userId = Auth::id();
$rank = $exam->marks()
            ->whereRaw(
                "marks > (select marks from exam_user where exam_id = {$exam->id} and user_id = {$userId}) limit 1"
            )
            ->count() + 1;
```